# how do i print all file names under a folder in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to display all the files in a folder in matlab. The following code is what i have so far

```
s = dir('D:\BOOKS');
```

Now it gives a struct with the following fields

```
    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
```

I need to loop through the name struct but how do i get its length ? my attempt

```
length(s.name); wont run
size(s.name); wont run
```

I am out of tries now. Could someone please help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = dir('D:\BOOKS');
for ii = 1:length(a);
fprintf('name %s\n',a(ii).name);
[pasthstr, name, extension] = fileparts(a(ii).name);
fprintf('name: %s, extension: %s\n', name, extension);
end;
```

Comment: it is very close to what i expected. However i also need the file extension and your answer doesn't seem to output it ?

Comment: MATLAB provides a convenience function for this task, see `fileparts`.

Comment: I get a blank result for extension ? Why is that

Comment: Looking at your example path your working on windows. The above example is successfully tested on OS X Lion.

Comment: oops now it works. I do not know what happened before that caused it not to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = dir('D:\BOOKS');
s={s.name}
```